# IBM IoT Real-Time insights chart visualizations

Tags: real-time, ibm-cloud, iot

Within the IBM IoT Real-Time insights we can display charts of data contained with incoming events.  Here is an example of such a chart:
[image]

What configuration do we have over the visualization?  For example:

- Can I control the boldness or visibility of division lines?
- Can I place labels on the X-Axis?
- Can I move the labels on the Y-Axis to the left of the chart?
- Can we plot marker points on the graph showing data points?
- Can we control the nature of the curve (it appears like some kind of best fit curve by default)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current implementation of the charts allows just a few options for customization, such as the color of the graphs and the size and position of the graph window. The other graph attributes mentioned above are not customizable at the moment.